# Timezone Independent countdown React/JS

Tags: javascript, date, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to create a timer with a GMT end date and a timezone independent start date so any user can follow the countdown accurately.

```
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const gmt = new Date(
        currentDate.getTime() + currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000
    );
    const endTime = 1666818000;
    const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setTime(SecondsToTime(endTime - Math.floor(gmt / 1000)));
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    });
```

getTime + timezoneOffset is not working.

```
let now = new Date();
    let nowUTC = new Date(
        now.getUTCFullYear(),
        now.getUTCMonth(),
        now.getUTCDate(),
        now.getUTCHours(),
        now.getUTCMinutes(),
        now.getUTCSeconds()
    );
```

this also does not work

Answer (score -1):

You can use [date-fns-tz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz) to format the time to UTC.

Example from their docs:

```
import { zonedTimeToUtc } from 'date-fns-tz'

const date = getDatePickerValue() // e.g. 2014-06-25 10:00:00 (picked in any time zone)
const timeZone = getTimeZoneValue() // e.g. America/Los_Angeles

const utcDate = zonedTimeToUtc(date, timeZone) // In June 10am in Los Angeles is 5pm UTC
```